# T-SQL query PIVOT

Tags: sql-server, pivot, pivot-table

I need your help to made a T-SQL Query with PIVOT function (MSSQL)
I have 3 tables :

**Project:**

```
Id | Name
 1 | PE1XX 
 2 | PE2YZ
```

**File**

```
Id | Name
 1 | ARM
 2 | LEX
 3 | FSP
```

**Control**

```
Id | IdProject  | IdFile| Result
 1 |     1      |   1   | 100
 2 |     1      |   2   | 50
 3 |     1      |   3   | 0 
 4 |     2      |   2   | 75
```

I want to see my data like this..

**Result Set**

```
ProjectName | ARM   | LEX   | FSP   | ...* 
PE1XX       | 100   | 50    | 0     | ...
PE2YZ       | NULL  | 75    | NULL  | ...
```

Today I made the result in my code with multiple foreach , but it is expensive in performance.

```
Foreach(p in Project){
  Foreach(f in File){
   var result = getFirstControl(p.IdProject, f.IdFile);
   ...
  }
}
```

I think we can use pivot function to do it faster but I have some problems to set it up in my case (the list of file can be modified)... And maybe I can do it more easily?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to go dynamic

```
Declare @SQL varchar(max) = Stuff((Select Distinct ',' + QuoteName( [Name]) From [File]  Order by 1 For XML Path('')),1,1,'') 
Select  @SQL = '
Select [ProjectName],' + @SQL + '
From (
        Select ProjectName = P.[Name]
              ,Item         = F.[Name]
              ,Value        = C.[Result]
        From [Control] C 
        Join [Project] P on C.IDProject = P.ID
        Join [File]    F on C.IDFile    = F.ID
       ) A
 Pivot (max(Value) For [Item] in (' + @SQL + ') ) p'
Exec(@SQL);
```

Returns

```
ProjectName ARM     FSP     LEX
PE1XX       100     0       50
PE2YZ       NULL    NULL    75
```

Answer (score 0):

Google how you would make this a dynamic pivot but if you were to hard code the values for the file names it would look something like.....

```
;WITH X AS (
Select f.Name [FileName]
      ,p.Name ProjectName
      ,C.Result
FROM [Control] C 
LEFT JOIN [File] F ON c.IdFile = F.Id
LEFT JOIN [Project] P ON p.Id = c.IdProject
)
SELECT ProjectName , ARM , LEX , FSP
FROM X 
 PIVOT (SUM(Result)
        FOR [FileName] 
        IN (ARM,LEX,FSP)
        )p
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from 
(
  select p.name pname,
  f.name fname,
  c.result
  from control c
  inner join project p
  on c.idproject = p.id
  inner join files f
  on c.idfile = f.id
) t
PIVOT
(
  sum(result) over fname in 
    ([ARM], [LEX], [FSP])
);
```

Comment: Please don't forget to explain / comment your code, and provide relevant documentation [from review]